# Windows batch: how to assign variable with dynamic name?

Tags: windows, batch-file

see the code snippet below. I would like to assign a dynamic name to a new variable. I tried the following:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set my_dir_1=C:\temp1
set my_dir_2=C:\temp2
for %%d in (1 2) do (
    echo my_dir_%%d: !my_dir_%%d!
    set new_var=!my_dir_%%d!
    echo === %new_var% ===
)

endlocal
```

The first "echo" will output what I want:

```
my_dir_1: C:\temp1
===  ===
my_dir_2: C:\temp2
===  ===
```

But as you can see at the second "echo" my new variable "new_var" is empty.
How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
echo === %new_var% ===
```

with this:

```
echo === !new_var! ===
```